# net-snmp (VACM): How to exclude IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress table column from view?

Tags: network-interface, snmp

Tailoring an SNMP view for net-snmp 5.7.3, I fail to exclude `IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress` from my view:
What ever I tried, I still get the MAC addresses in `snmpwalk`.
Still I'm sure my view is being used as other excludes *do* work.

So here is my last attempt:

```text
view publ included .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2 fc
# iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1)

view publ excluded .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.ifTable.ifEntry.ifPhysAddress ff:c0
# 1 3 6 1 2 1 interfaces(2) ifTable(2) ifEntry(1) ifPhysAddress(6)
# .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6

# this works:
view publ excluded .1.3.6.1.2.1.ip fe
# ip(4)
```

### Update (2021-01-08)

The OID and mask given initially were wrong, causing error `bad SUBTREE object id`.
Still, even with the fixed OID and mask the `ifPhysAddress` entries are still included in the view.

### Update (2021-01-27)

I found out that using the symbolic names causes the problem:
If I use only numeric IDs, it works.

Still, I don't know what causes the problem:
The `IF-MIB.txt` is located in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs`, it contains the definitions being used, and it is included in the `net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs`.

This syntax is accepted, but the table column is not excluded:

```text
view publ excluded IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress ff:c0
```

Comment: I'm surprised that no-one seems to know the answer, even after a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a non-issue; exactly it was a `1` vs. `l` font confusion:
I had mixed view names `vPubl` and `vPub1`, but with the font being used in PuTTY, I didn't see the difference:

[image: PuTTY screenshot showing snmp.conf in Emacs]